# Are the jQuery UI language files hosted on Google's CDN?

Tags: jquery-ui, cdn

Do Google host the language files for jQuery UI or do I need host them myself?

If they do, is there a way to include them like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the language localizations hosted here: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
```

[Here's the uncompressed view in case you want to see what you're working with](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.js).

Answer (score 0):

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Css:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
```

Images are relative to the stylesheet directory

See http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#jqueryUI 
for details.

Comment: These are the styles and images...by the title though, I think he's looking for the language localizations, not the stylesheets :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what @Darryl wants :)

[Here you have the i18n](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js)